# Using cypress how do I check that a background image has loaded?

Tags: cypress

Writing my first cypress test in conjunction with percy visual tester.  I load my landing page, check a few links and then take a percy snapshot.  The issue is that the background image hasn't loaded in the snapshot.

I can get it to appear by artifically waiting before taking the snapshot, but I'd prefer to have a cypress assertion to check this instead.

Here is the css:

`.bg-hero {
    @include image("/images/background/landing.jpg", center);
  }`

Here is the html:
`<div class="bg-hero bg top-header bg-header-top" id="#"></div>`

I tried: `cy.get('.bg-hero').should('be.visible');`

Am currently using: `cy.wait(3000);`

thanks

Comment: this seems to be a known issue with Percy, see issue here: https://github.com/percy/percy-cypress/issues/134

Answer (score 1):

You can use Route command as this

```
cy.route('imageURL').as('image')
cy.wait('@image')
cy.get('.bg-hero').should('be.visible');
```

Comment: I tried this approach with no success.  There is no XHR request logged in the test runner that would facilitate this.  I just got errors saying that no request ever occurred.

Comment: try using timeout as this cy.get('.bg-hero').should('be.visible',{timeout:10000});

Comment: not sure that it is much better than just calling wait as I was..

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with Percy and not Cypress.  I had to tweak a setting such that Percy would wait a while longer.  [Percy command line docs reference a network idle timeout setting](https://docs.percy.io/docs/command-line-client#section--network-idle-timeout-t).  Thanks to Rob@Percy for putting me onto this. It has made my visual testing much more robust.